# docker-compose on Windows volume not working

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, docker-volume

I've been playing with Docker for the past week and think the container idea is very useful, but despite reading everything I can for the past 3 days I can't get the volume mapping to work

```
get docker-compose to use my existing volume.

    Docker Version: 18.03.1-ce
    docker-compose version 1.21.1, build 7641a569

I created a volume using the following via a Dockerfile

    # Reference SQL image
    FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer

    # Create directory within SQL container for database files mapped to the    volume
    VOLUME sqldata:c:/MSSQL

and here it shows:
    C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes>docker volume ls
    local               sqldata

Now I've tried probably 60+ different "solutions" based on StackOverflow and Docker forums, but none of them work. (Note despite the names below with Azure I am simply trying to get this to run locally, Azure is next hurdle)

    Docker-compose.yaml:

    version: '3.4'
    services:
      ws:
        image: wsManager
        container_name: azure-wcf
        ports:
           - "80"
        depends_on:
            - db

      db:
        image: dbimage:latest
        container_name: azure-db
        volumes:
             - \sqldata:/mssql
#            - type: volume
#              source: sqldata
#              target: /mssql
        ports:
            - "1433"

I've added a volumes section but it does not help, 

    volumes:
        sqldata:
            external:
                name: sqldata

    changed the - \sqldata:/mssql
    to every possible slash .. . ~ whatever.  Moved the file to yaml file
```

to        C:\ProgramData\Docker\volumes - basically any suggestion that showed in my search results.  The dbImage is a SQL Server image that I need to persist the data from but am wondering what the magic is as nothing I've tried works.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

I'm running on Windows 10 Pro build 1803.

Why does this have to be so hard?
Than you to whomever knows how to make this actually work.

Comment: Well I was able to figure this out finally, and the following helped: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905797/docker-compose-how-to-initialize-sql-server-db-on-windows-container) along with some documentation on Microsoft's site.  I changed the applicable part of the yaml file as follows: 
  sqldb:
    image: dbimage:latest
    container_name: azure-db
    volumes:
        - "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\volumes\\sqldata:c:\\mssql"

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to reference the true path on Windows using the *volumes*: option as below:

```
sqldb:
    image: sqlimage 
    container_name: azure-db
    volumes:
      - "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\volumes\\sqldata:c:\\mssql"
```

To persist the data I used the following:

```
environment:
   - "sa_password=ddsql2017@@"
   - "ACCEPT_EULA=Y"
   - 'attach_dbs= {"dbName":"MyDb","dbFiles":"C:\\MSSQL\\MyDb.mdf","C:\\MSSQL\\MyDb.ldf"]}]'
```

Hope this helps someone else as many of the examples I found searching both on SO and elsewhere did not work for me, and in the Docker forums there are a lot of posts saying mounting volumes not work for Windows.

Comment: I have been using a ton of hours figuring out the mount syntax, especially the -"c:\\ etc." part. FINALLY... Huge thanks, you saved me.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using Ubunto WSL:

- `sudo mkdir /c`
- `sudo mount --bind /mnt/c /c`
- navigate to your project file use new path ( /c/your-project-path and not /mnt/c/your-project-path)
- edit your docker-compose.yml and use relative path for volume : ( like ./src instead of c/your-project-path/src)
- `docker-compose up`

Comment: You're a hero, mate. Nothing else helped, I've been digging through tens of different SO and github issues, this finally worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with a similar problem when trying to mount a volume to a specific path of my Windows machine: basically it didn't work so every time I restarted my Docker instance I lose all my DB data.
I finally found out that it is because Docker for Windows by default cannot interpret Windows path so the flag COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS has to be activated. To do so:

- Run the command "set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1"
- Restart Docker
- Go to Settings > Shared Drives > Reset credentials and then select drive and then apply
- From the command line, kill the containers (docker container rm -f )
- Re-run the containers

Hope it helps

Comment: Also you can put COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 in .env file in case if command "set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1" not persist. After that inside docker-compose.yml file ${PWD} also shold work!

Answer (score 3):

If your windows account credentials has been changed, you also have to reset credentials for shared drives. (Settings > Shared Drives > Reset credentials)

In my case, the password was changed by my company security policy.

Comment: yes it work also for me! this is the official docker issue/solution https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/182

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you really need to map to a certain host directory? If not, my solution is to create a volume beforehand and use it in docker-compose.yaml. I use the same scripts for both windows and linux. That is the beauty of docker.
Here is what I did to start both postgres and mysql:

create_db.sh (you can run it in git bash or similiar environment in windows):

```
docker volume create --name postgres-data -d local
docker volume create --name mysql-data -d local
docker-compose up -d
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: datasource
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'train'
      MYSQL_USER: 'mysql'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'mysql'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'mysql'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    postgres-data:
      external: true
    mysql-data:
      external: true
```

Answer (score 1):

By default it looks that after installing Docker on Windows, sharing of drivers is disabled - so you won't be able to use volumes(that are stored on disks)

Enabling such sharing, through: `Docker in tray - right click - Settings`, helped to me, volumes started working fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docker on Windows is having strange behavior as Windows has limitations with credentials and also with the virtual machine that Docker is using(Hyper-V , VirtualBox - depending on your Docker version and setup).

Basically, you are correct to map a folder in

> volumes:

section in your service:

The path is

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    image: dbimage:latest
    container_name: azure-db
    volumes:
         - c:/Temp/sqldata:/mssql
```

Important is that you do not need to explicitly create volume in volumes section, but the docker-compose up will create it(the same is for docker run).

Strange thing is that it will never show up in

> docker volume ls

but it will be usable with the same files inside windows directory and inside container path /mssql

You can test it with:

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Temp/sqldata:/data alpine ls /data
```

or

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Temp:/data alpine ls /data
```

If it Disappear, probably it lost the credentials and Reset it via Docker->Settings->Shared Drives->Reset credentials.

I hope it was clear and covered all the aspects for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch Docker from your windows taskbar
2. Click on Settings icon on top
3. Click Resources
4. Click File Sharing
5. Click on (+) sign and add path of local folder in which you want to map the container volume.

It worked for me.